# Bash - Increment the version number by 1

Tags: bash, shell

I'm new to bash script. I need to bump up the version number of my build by 1.

For eg:- if my version is `1.0.0+1`, bumping it would generate `1.0.1+2`, ie basically incrementing the number by 1 before and after `+`.

How can this be done in bash script?

Comment: Maybe because you haven't shown your attempts?

Comment: I'm new to Bash. I'm a python guy. I could do the same in Python, but not bash.

Comment: You can do it in Python and capture its output in bash.

Comment: Yes, that's a possibility. But don't want to mix 2 things when the same can be done in bash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bash approach which is basically close to Python style is to use a regular expression to separate the version number and the rest of the version string:

```
version=1.0.0+1
if [[ $version =~ ^([^+?]*[.])([0-9]*)[+]([0-9]+) ]]
then
  # ... see below
else
  echo Unexpected version string: "$version"
fi
```

When you have a match, you can refer to the capture groups in the regexp. In Python you would use something like `result.group(1)` to access the groups. In bash, you have for this purpose a single, predefined array `BASH_REMATCH`, which always refers to the most recent regexp matching. In our case, we would have

```
 version_string_head=${BASH_REMATCH[1]} # 1.0. 
 version_count_hi=${BASH_REMATCH[2]} # 0
 version_count_lo=${BASH_REMATCH[3]} # 1
```

The rest is trivial:

```
new_version_string=${version_string_head}$((version_count_hi + 1))+$((version_count_lo + 1))
```

Comment: Last *two* numbers should be incremented.

Comment: Ah, missed that. Of course my approach can easily adapted to this. Will fix my post.

Comment: @choroba : I also had a typo in the variable name, but should be OK now. Please check ....